# Parsing XML with T-SQL in two separate tables

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2012 and trying to parse an XML to 2 separate tables in my database. Normally 1 table would be enough, but not in this instance. My XML is structured as follows (I can't change it's structure, I already receive it like that)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <podjetje id="" storitev="" uporabnik="" ts="" opis_storitve="">
  <izdelki>
  <izdelek st="1">
      <izdelekID>ID</izdelekID> 
      <ean>EAN CODE</ean> 
      <izdelekIme>PRODUCT NAME</izdelekIme> 
      <url>WEBSITE</url> 
      <kratkiopis>SHORT DESCRIPTION</kratkiopis> 
      <opis>DESCRIPTION</opis> 
      <dodatneLastnosti>ATTRIBUTES</dodatneLastnosti> 
      <slikaVelika>BIG PICTURE URL</slikaVelika> 
      <dodatneSlike>
          <dodatnaSlika1>EXTRA IMAGE URL</dodatnaSlika1> 
          <dodatnaSlika2>EXTRA IMAGE URL2</dodatnaSlika2> 
          <dodatnaSlika3>EXTRA IMAGE URL3</dodatnaSlika3> 
      </dodatneSlike>
  </izdelek>
  </izdelki>
  </podjetje>
```

To insert this XML into a table i use SQL bulk insert

```
SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO tmpImport(XmlCol)

SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @ImportFileName + ''', SINGLE_BLOB, ERRORFILE = ''' + @BulkLoadFilePath + ''') AS x '

EXECUTE (@SQLString)
```

I can handle most of the data without any problems. I ran into some problems when i get to the node "dodatneSlike". The idea is, that each article has some pictures. The main picture is in the node "slikaVelika" and I can insert it into my table. There are extra pictures in the child nodes of node "dodatneSlike". This is causing me problems, because I have to insert these extra pictures into a separate table (inserting the picture from node "slikaVelika" would also help, but I think i can get around it if it's not possible). The table is nothing special, just the Article ID from node "izdelekID" and the pictures from "dodatneSlike".

The problem is, I never know how many nodes ("dodatnaSlika1", "dodatnaSlika2",...) there will be. There might be 1, 10, 0....

So my question is how do I get the values from "dodatnaSlika" nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the native XQuery support in SQL Server! Much easier than the clunky old `OPENROWSET` stuff....

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <podjetje id="" storitev="" uporabnik="" ts="" opis_storitve="">
  <izdelki>
  <izdelek st="1">
      <izdelekID>ID</izdelekID> 
      <ean>EAN CODE</ean> 
      <izdelekIme>PRODUCT NAME</izdelekIme> 
      <url>WEBSITE</url> 
      <kratkiopis>SHORT DESCRIPTION</kratkiopis> 
      <opis>DESCRIPTION</opis> 
      <dodatneLastnosti>ATTRIBUTES</dodatneLastnosti> 
      <slikaVelika>BIG PICTURE URL</slikaVelika> 
      <dodatneSlike>
          <dodatnaSlika1>EXTRA IMAGE URL</dodatnaSlika1> 
          <dodatnaSlika2>EXTRA IMAGE URL2</dodatnaSlika2> 
          <dodatnaSlika3>EXTRA IMAGE URL3</dodatnaSlika3> 
      </dodatneSlike>
  </izdelek>
  </izdelki>
  </podjetje>'

SELECT
    izdelek_st = @input.value('(/podjetje/izdelki/izdelek/@st)[1]', 'int'),
    izdelekID = @input.value('(/podjetje/izdelki/izdelek/izdelekID)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ean = @input.value('(/podjetje/izdelki/izdelek/ean)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),

    XC.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    XC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/podjetje/izdelki/izdelek/dodatneSlike/*') AS XT(XC)
```

This will give you all the subnodes under `<dodatneSlike>` - no matter how many there are - and it gives you both the **node name**, as well as the **node value**.

**Update:** assuming you have *multiple* `<izdelek>` nodes, then you could use this query instead:

```
SELECT
    izdelek_st = @input.value('(/podjetje/izdelki/izdelek/@st)[1]', 'int'),

    izdelekID = xc1.value('(izdelekID)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ean = xc1.value('(ean)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),

    XC2.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    XC2.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/podjetje/izdelki/izdelek') AS XT1(XC1)
CROSS APPLY
    xc1.nodes('dodatneSlike/*') AS XT2(XC2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Still not quite where I want to be with this... I can get the content of nodes "dodatneSlike", now I'm having trouble getting the article ID for those pictures ("izdelekID"). Whatever I try I always get the ID of the  first article in my XML for all the pictures (I get the pictures for all articles but the ID of only the first article.).

Comment: @Miha: I only see one single `izdelekID` in your XML - how and where are those "several" ID's ?? Your sample doesn't show that....

Comment: I realize that my sample wasn't the best one around... Sorry about that. The XML is 3,5MB in size, there are about 1000 articles in it. I just copied 1 article out and changed the values (I cant show you the original because of sensitive data). The structure is the same for other articles, only the data is different. I am also wondering if there is any chance that I could count the number of "dodatnaSlika" nodes for 1 article (I would like to add a Position field for every picture, that resets for every article).

Comment: @Miha: see my update trying to cope with multiple `<izdelek>` nodes in your XML